# /tmp vs. /dev/shm for temp file storage on Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-memory, temporary-files

I have scripts that make hundreds of quick succession, small, temp files needing to be created and very soon read back in, then unlinked.

My testing shows little if any performance difference by putting said files in `/tmp` (to disk) or into `/dev/shm` (filesystem-level shared memory) on Linux even under moderate load.  I attribute this to the filesystem cache.

Granted the disk will *eventually* get hit with the fileystem actions, but on multiple small write-read temp files, why would you (not) recommend `/dev/shm` over disk-backed directory?  Have you noticed big performance increases with shared memory directory over a cached VFS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`/dev/shm` is intended for a very special purpose, not for files to be put to by arbitrary programs.

In contrast, `/tmp` is [exactly made for this](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES). On my systems, `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` as well, in contrast to `/var/tmp` which is [designed](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARTMPTEMPORARYFILESPRESERVEDBETWEE) for putting larger files, potentially staying longer.

Comment: +1  `/dev/shm` being a general-purpose `tmpfs` is an implementation detail of Linux, not a guarantee in any way (available space is usually very limited anyhow).  Use `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` for what they were intended for.  And depending on the usage and filesystem, if you creat and unlink a file, it's possible it will be in cache only and never hit disk.

Comment: @ephemient - a file create and immediate unlink even if cached would eventually hit the disk, no?

Comment: @glglgl - On the systems into which we're deploying (in a managed services scenario) /tmp is backed not by `tmpfs` but by the primary sda1 disk.  Otherwise, I'd agree to keep with standard, but that's our deployment environment at this time.

Comment: What is the 'special purpose'?

Comment: @tkarls With [`shm_open(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open) you can request that a special "shared memory" object is created. Some implementations (or Linux in general?) uses `/dev/shm` for putting the created objects.

Answer (score 2):

It is essentially the same (shm is also backed implicitly by the disk when you have a swapfile).

/tmp has the advantage that it fills up harder (considering your hard disk is likely larger than your swapfile). And also it is more widely supported.