# Redirecting `sys.stdout` to a file or a buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I am working in Python 3.4, and I have behavior that I don't understand: if I redirect stdout to a file, I am able to capture text from child processes. However, when I redirect to a Python file object, I stop capturing that output. I would love an explanation of the (following) behavior.

I have:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker():
    print('forked output')

def output():
    print('redirected')
    p = Process(target=worker)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join()  # wait for subprocess to terminate
    print('end')
```

The `redirect_stdout` context manager in Python 3.4 makes grabbing stdout easy (in this instance).

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from sys import stdout
from tempfile import TemporaryFile


with TemporaryFile(mode='w+', encoding=stdout.encoding) as buf:
    with redirect_stdout(buf):
        output()  # the function defined above
    buf.seek(0)
    s = buf.read()
    print('output from TemporaryFile:')
    print(s)
```

I can then simply call the script to get the following output:

```
$ python stackoverflow.py 
output from TemporaryFile:
redirected
forked output
end
```

This is exactly what I want, and works fine.

My confusion stems from the fact that if I if I switch `TemporaryFile` with `TextIOWrapper`, the behavior of my script changes.

```
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper


with TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(), stdout.encoding) as buf:
    with redirect_stdout(buf):
        output()  # the function defined at the start
    buf.seek(0)
    s = buf.read()
    print('output from TextIO:')
    print(s)
```

Now when I call the program, I lose the output from the forked process.

```
$ python stackoverflow.py 
output from TextIO:
redirected
end
```

What is going on?

I suspect the problem has to do with the fact that the `TextIOWrapper` object doesn't have a file descriptor, and that `os.fork()` (used by `multiprocessing`) may thus be replacing the `TextIOWrapper` with another, but I admit some confusion there (especially given that stdout appears to be a `TextIOWrapper` *with* `fileno()` implemented).

```
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> stdout.fileno()
1
>>> stdout
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Thanks for any information.

Comment: I believe you're on the right track. I don't have enough to post an answer, but I think it is an issue with file descriptors; sys.stdout has a system-level descriptor, whereas TextIOWrapper is internal to Python.

Comment: @Cyphase I am almost absolutely sure you are correct. Redirecting `stdout`, `stderr` or `stdin` is an OS level operation, not a python operation. It works on file descriptors. A `BytesIO` object has no file descriptor because it is strictly a blob of bytes in memory. `TemporaryFile` is the way to go. On Linux if you create the file in the directory `/dev/shm`, it never hits an actually disk drive (although, arguably, [using `/tmp` won't either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745281/tmp-vs-dev-shm-for-temp-file-storage-on-linux)).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using multiprocessing, you should use the [standard message passing primitives](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) provided by that library.  Do not call `print()` from the subprocess; that's poor design.

If you're actually trying to make this work with someone else's (non-Python) code, use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) or another of the subprocess functions instead.