# What type of memory objects does `shm_open` use?

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory

Usually, shared memory is implemented using portions of On-Disk files mapped to processes address spaces. Whenever a memory access occurs on the shared region, the filesystem is involved to write changes on the disk which is a great overhead.
 Typically, a call to `fopen()` returns a file descriptor which is passed to `mmap()` to create the file's memory map. `shm_open`, apparently, works in the same way. It returns a file descriptor which can even be used with regular file operations (e.g `ftruncate`, `ftell`, `fseek` ...etc). We do specify a string as a parameter to `shm_open` but unlike `fopen()`, it is not a name of a real file on the visible filesystem (mounted HDD, Flash drives, SSD ... etc). The same string name can be used by totally unrelated processes to map the same region into their address spaces.
So, what is the string parameter passed to `shm_open` & what does `shm_open` creates/opens ? Is it a file on some temporary filesystem (/tmp) which is eventually used by many processes to create the shared region (Well, i think it has to be some kind of files since it returns a file descriptor) ? Or is it some kind of a mysterious and hidden filesystem backed by the kernel ?
People say `shm_open` is faster then `fopen` because no disk operations are involved so the theory i suggest is that the kernel uses an invisible RAM-based filesystem to implement shared memory with `shm_open` !

Comment: Why do you think shared memory is mapped to disk?

Comment: on linux shm_open would normally create a device `file` in /dev/shm.

Comment: Btw oracle uses shared memory and it does not go to disk

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745281/tmp-vs-dev-shm-for-temp-file-storage-on-linux

Comment: @EdHeal I know that not all implementations of shared memory are mapped to disk but a lot of usual ones are.

Comment: Please could you give me a reference

Comment: No, the disk is not relevant. You could use `shm_open` without any swap. See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), and `/dev/shm/` is generally a [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) mounted file system so dont use any disk.

Comment: @EdHeal I don't have any references but just consider the case of mapping a disk file to memory and using it as a shared object. You will have to confirm that data is written back to the file (using `msync`) to make sure synchronization is happening as expected (i mean updates are taking place in all other processes memory maps).

Comment: Are we talking about shared memory or memory mapped files? The two things are different

Comment: @EdHeal I think shared memory is implemented using memory mapped files, isn't it ?

Comment: 1. Surely shared memory is just that - perhaps using the metaphor of file handles etc it is just memory - not disk. 2. You are contradicting yourself from about two hours ago. 3. Database require shared memory to be just memory. Other wise there is no performance gain when a database cannot control that aspect of hardware

Comment: Also please find a reference for you assumptins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Usually, shared memory is implemented using portions of On-Disk files mapped to processes address spaces. Whenever a memory access occurs on the shared region, the filesystem is involved to write changes on the disk which is a great overhead.

That seems rather presumptuous, and not entirely correct.  Substantially all machines that implement shared memory regions (in the IPC sense) have virtual memory units by which they support the feature.  There may or may not be any persistent storage backing any particular shared memory segment, or any part of it.  Only the part, if any, that is paged out needs to be backed by such storage.

> `shm_open`, apparently, works in the same way. It returns a file descriptor which can even be used with regular file operations (e.g `ftruncate`, `ftell`, `fseek` ...etc).

That `shm_open()` has an interface modeled on that of `open()`, and that it returns a file descriptor that can meaningfully be used with certain general-purpose I/O function, do not imply that `shm_open()` "works in the same way" in any broader sense.  Pretty much all system resources are represented to processes as files.  This affords a simpler overall system interface, but it does not imply any commonality of the underlying resources beyond the fact that they can be manipulated via the same functions -- to the extent that indeed they can be.

> So, what is the string parameter passed to `shm_open` & what does `shm_open` creates/opens ?

The parameter is a string identifying the shared memory segment.  You already knew that, but you seem to think there's more to it than that.  There isn't, at least not at the level (POSIX) at which the `shm_open` interface is specified.  The identifier is meaningful primarily to the kernel.  Different implementations handle the details differently.

> Is it a file on some temporary filesystem (/tmp) which is eventually used by many processes to create the shared region

Could be, but probably isn't.  Any filesystem interface provided for it is likely (but not certain) to be a virtual filesystem, not actual, accessible files on disk.  Persistent storage, if used, is likely to be provided out of the system's swap space.

> (Well, i think it has to be some kind of files since it returns a file descriptor) ?

Such a conclusion is unwarranted.  Sockets and pipes are represented via file descriptors, too, but they don't have corresponding accessible files.

> Or is it some kind of a mysterious and hidden filesystem backed by the kernel ?

That's probably a better conception, though again, there might not be any persistent storage at all.  To the extent that there is any, however, it is likely to be part of the system's swap space, which is not all that mysterious.

Answer (score 7):

> Usually, shared memory is implemented using portions of On-Disk files mapped to processes address spaces.

This is generally false, at least on a desktop or laptop running a recent Linux distribution, with some reasonable amount of RAM (e.g. 8Gbytes at least).

So, the disk is not relevant. You could use `shm_open` without any swap. See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), and notice that `/dev/shm/` is generally a [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) mounted file system so don't use any disk. See [tmpfs(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html). And `tmpfs` don't use the disk (unless you reach [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) conditions, which is unlikely) since it works in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

> the filesystem is involved to write changes on the disk which is a great overhead.

This is usually wrong. On most systems, recently written files are in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), which does not reach the disk quickly (BTW, that is why the shutdown procedure needs to call [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) which is rarely used otherwise...).

BTW, on most desktops and laptops, it is easy to observe. The hard disk has some LED, and you won't see it blinking when using `shm_open` and related calls. BTW, you could also use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (notably `/proc/diskstats` etc....) to query the kernel about its disk activity.

Comment: Now it makes sense. So the parameter passed to `shm_open` is the filename on /dev/shm/ `tempfs` filesystem ?

Comment: Yes, and that is documented in [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html). You should read documentation and `man` pages before asking questions on SO or elsewhere.